# Is it possible to map a CSS class selector to a tag selector?

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages, css-selectors

More specifically, given a set of style sheets that define a class selector called "content_title", is there a way to apply that style to all `<h1>` tags without changing each one to `<h1 class="content_title">`, i.e. to effectively apply that class to all instances of a given element?

The context is that I'm trying to apply HTML and CSS from a graphic designer to existing web applications and some of the selectors don't match up very well.

I have an ASP.NET web forms application that uses master pages and a theme.  I've been given an HTML sample/template that that includes several style sheets.

So I updated my master page to use the new design, and now it looks something like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="MyMaster.master.vb" Inherits="MyApp.MyMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <!-- these are the new style sheet from the graphic designer -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../layout.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../cssmenus.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dropdown.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../print.css" media="print" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body class="twocolumn">
    <div id="container">
        <!-- etc. etc. -->

            <div id="mainContent_app">
                    <span class="content_title"></span> <!-- this is intended to be a page header/title -->

                    <form id="form1" runat="server">
                    <div>
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainForm" runat="server">
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
            <!-- end #mainContent -->

        <!-- etc. etc. -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that where the designer uses `<span class="content_title"></span>` to represent the page header, I've used `<h1>` in all the content pages.  For example:

```
<%@ Page Title="Simple single serving form" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/MyMaster.Master" CodeBehind="MyPage.aspx.vb" Inherits="MyApp.MyPage" Theme="MyTheme" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <meta name="keywords" content="keyword1 keyword2 keyword3" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainForm" runat="server">
    <h1>This is the page header.</h1>
    <p>Here's some text that tells you what to do with this form.</p>
</asp:Content>
```

My goal is to use the designer's style without having to edit every content page that includes an `<h1>`.

I could copy the styles from the designer's CSS to the stylsheet in my app's Theme (substituting the class selector for the tag, of course), but then i wouldn't really be using the source CSS and I'd have to do this again the next time the external CSS changes.

I'm also not likely to get the external CSS changed to fit my app.

So is there something clever I can do to make `<h1>` == `class="content_title"` with respect to the application of styles, or will I have to bite the bullet and update each and every one of my content pages?

Comment: Just bite the bullet. How hard is it really to run a global find and replace for `<h1>` to `<h1 class="content_title">`?

Comment: why not change the css from `.content_title {properties}` to `.content_title, h1 {properties}`? If I understood correct your requirement.

Comment: @Sotiris "I'm also not likely to get the external CSS changed to fit my app." - He can't actually edit the css

Comment: @thirtydot - not that hard, really. :)  I'm probably just over-thinking this one because it feels like the class selector really _should have been_ a tag selector given the way it's used, and my CSS is rudimentary enough to make me wonder what I don't know.  Thanks for the reality check.

Comment: @Matt: Whoever wrote `<span class="content_title"></span>` should be.. *educated* that titles should almost always be `<h[1..6]>` tags.

Comment: @thirtydot That seems reasonable to me, but I felt to compelled to search/ask.  btw, if the real answer to my original question, "Is is possible to map a ..." is literally "no, it's not possible", that's an answer I'd be inclined to accept.  I really didn't know what I didn't know, if you know what I mean.

Comment: @Matt: It is not possible to make a plain `<h1>` tag pick up on styles set on a `.content_title` selector, without changing the CSS. The smallest change you could make to do it is that suggested by @Sotiris, which is very minimal.

Comment: Late to the game, but yes, please use modify the HTML if you can (these are just templates, right?). I upvoted both @thirtydot's and @Robert Koritnik's answers.

Comment: I think you can just create a CSS style called "h1" and change it from there? I have done that with "a" and "p" and "div" why not h1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just bite the bullet. How hard is it really to run a global find and replace for `<h1>` to `<h1 class="content_title">`?

Whoever wrote `<span class="content_title"></span>` should be.. *educated* that titles should almost always be `<h[1..6]>` tags.

It is not possible to make a plain `<h1>` tag pick up on styles set on a `.content_title` selector, without changing the CSS. The smallest change you could make to do it is that suggested by @Sotiris, which is very minimal.

You may recognize the text of this answer from.. *somewhere* ;)

Answer (score 5):

### Don't overcomplicate things

Seems to me this is a very simple **Replace in Files** scenario. I'd search for `<h1>` in all my files and replace that with `<h1 class="content_title">`.

I know this is not what you wanted since it seems tedious but you have this capability in Visual Studio directly. So you can replace all `H1` elements in one go. It would take you what? Few seconds? If you use different kinds of `H1` elements (some that already use `class` attributes and you'd like to add this additional class, you can do the same but you'll have to use some regular expression to do the searching and replacement.

### Why is Javascript not beneficial here?

If you use JavaScript for this kind of thing it doesn't seem reasonable, since long documents will get transformed while user may already see the content. And I don't see a reason why one would want to do this using JavaScript and put a burden on the client side **on every request** instead of changing this **once on the server**. This is a very good example of **over-engineering**. Another surface where bugs can sprout. You should avoid such situations.

If your designer decides to change the CSS your H1 elements will change as well. But if designer decides to change CSS class name from content_title to something else, your H1 elements won't follow. **But** they wouldn't follow by using JavaScript either. So it practically the same if you just do a **replace in files**.

### Best solution

Open CSS file and change the code that says:

```
/* maybe some selectors here */ .content_title
{
    ...
}
```

to

```
h1,
/* maybe some selectors here */ .content_title
{
    ...
}
```

The smallest amount of work you can do. And when designer changes styles, they will get changed for both definitions so you won't have to copy styles to your `H1` definition. Voila problem solved.

Comment: +1 You're right. I like the KISS principle and now I suggested jQuery. I was wrong. Based on the information in the question this is the best solution.

Comment: One of those +1 is from me, this is a nice detailed answer.

Comment: +1 for "Don't overcomplicate things"; sometimes I need a reminder. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jquery, you can run something like:

```
jQuery(function($){$('h1').addClass('content_title');});
```

[edit]
Good intention replaced with correct answer. Thanks Brian!

Comment: Not using jQuery in this case.  Good idea, though.

Comment: You mean `jQuery(function($){$('h1').addClass('content_title');});` right? ;)

Comment: Woops. It was late (after midnight) when I wrote that. :) Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the problem you're having with this designer's styles will not be your last. I would create and manage a separate CSS file named something obvious like, "style_overrides.css". Make sure that file gets declared after the original styles. Then, copy the `.content-title` declaration into your new file and modify the selector to read `.content-title, H1`.

**I know it's not very DRY**, but it will allow you to override the multitude of mistakes (just a guess) that were made in the original styles. I suppose if you were up to the task, you could write some bomb-ass ASP script that searches the original CSS files for pre-specified declarations and applies the necessary modifications before writing a new CSS file. Although, that almost certainly isn't worth your time...